# Dimensions of a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I found this pretty awesome blog post that explains how to resize a canvas to fit any screen http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/casestudies/gopherwoord-studios-resizing-html5-games/ I implemented it and it is sizing it flawlessly but I get this problem that my objects appear off screen when the canvas is too little.

For example for my game I define a world with dimensions width 480 and height 1024, if I put an element on x axis at about 400 but the display that is currently used is 360px wide then the canvas would have correct ratio of width to height `0.46875` but the object will not be visible.

To solve this problem I suppose I need to define a ratio between the absolute world dimensions and the screen dimensions and multiply by that when I'm calculating the object's position, however my question is - is there a way for the canvas to do that automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Both the canvas itself and the canvas element have a width and height. If they're not the same, the content of the canvas is automatically scaled to fit the element. So yes, you could define your canvas to be the size you want, and define the element such that it scales. Naturally, though, *everything* scales, and if the aspect ratio is different, your shapes get distorted.

The width and height of the canvas within the `canvas` element are controlled by the `width` and `height` attributes of the `canvas` element. (They default to 300 and 150, respectively.)

The width and height of the canvas *element* are controlled by CSS; they default to the `width` and `height` of the canvas, but you can override that with CSS.

For example: Here's a canvas that's 300x300 (thanks to the CSS), within a canvas element that's only 300x150 (because those are the default width and height of the `canvas` element). You can see the effect of scaling when I draw a circle in it — it comes out oval instead:

```js
// Get the canvas element
const canvas = document.getElementById("clock");
// Get the 2D rendering context for it
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Show the canvas's dimensions (NOT the dimensions of the element)
document.getElementById("dimensions").innerHTML = canvas.width + "x" + canvas.height;

// Draw a circle -- it comes out oval because of scaling
const path = new Path2D();
path.arc(75, 75, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
context.fillStyle = context.strokeStyle = "blue";
context.fill(path);
```

```css
canvas#clock {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #1E1E1E;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="clock"></canvas>
<div id="dimensions"></div>
```

Here's an example where the canvas and its container are the same width and height, so there's no scaling; the code is identical, it's just I've added `width="300" height="300"` to the `canvas` HTML:

```js
// Get the canvas element
const canvas = document.getElementById("clock");
// Get the 2D rendering context for it
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Show the canvas's dimensions (NOT the dimensions of the element)
document.getElementById("dimensions").innerHTML = canvas.width + "x" + canvas.height;

// Draw a circle
const path = new Path2D();
path.arc(75, 75, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
context.fillStyle = context.strokeStyle = "blue";
context.fill(path);
```

```css
canvas#clock {
    /* We could comment out the width and height properties
       since they'll default to the values from the attributes
    */
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #1E1E1E;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="clock" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<div id="dimensions"></div>
```

The automatic scaling is handy provided you ensure the aspect ratio of the element and its canvas are the same. If you don't directly set the size of the canvas element, on most browsers it will default to the aspect ratio of the canvas thanks to the `width` and `height` attributes. From [MDN's coverage of `aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio):

> Browsers have added an internal `aspect-ratio` property that applies to replaced elements and other related elements that accept `width` and `height` attributes. This appears in the browser's internal UA stylesheet.
>
> In Firefox, the internal stylesheet rule looks like this:
>
> ```css
> img, input[type="image"], video, embed, iframe, marquee, object, table {
>   aspect-ratio: attr(width) / attr(height);
> }
> ```